# Convert byte[] array to Unicode, UnicodeWithBOM etc

Tags: java, arrays, character-encoding

I have a byte[] array and I have to convert it to "**Unicode, UnicodeWithBOM, UTF-8 e.t.c**"

I tried ICU library but unable to find any solution.

is there any functions available in ICU for java to **ConvertToUnicode,ConvertToUnicodeWithBOM,ConvertFromUnicode e.t.c**

Please refer to the ICU library for the java

[Please refer the ICU library for the java](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/)

I have gone through the library but unable to find the exact class and the methods which will convert a particular source string into another format.

e.g: I have an array of a byte in UTF-8 format and I wanted the same to be converted into the byte array of **ANSCI/UTF-16/**

My input

```
The language samples below were generated using Google Translate.

Welcome to Unicode and International language support for source materials in our product.
[English]

مرحبا بكم في ويونيكود الدعم الدولي لمواد اللغة مصدر في منتجاتنا.
[Arabic]

歡迎國際語言支持Unicode和源材料在我們的產品。
[Chinese (Traditional)]

Καλώς ήρθατε στο Unicode και διεθνή γλωσσική υποστήριξη για πρώτες ύλες για το προϊόν μας.
[Greek]

ברוכים הבאים ל-Unicode ותמיכה בינלאומית השפה עבור חומרי המקור של המוצר שלנו.
[Hebrew]

Velkomin á Unicode og alþjóðleg tungumál styðja fyrir efni sem uppspretta í vörum okkar.
[Icelandic]

ようこそUnicodeと私たちの製品のソースの材料のための国際言語のサポート。
[Japanese]

Добро пожаловать в Unicode и международной языковой поддержки для исходных материалов в нашей продукции.
[Russian]
```

Expected output if i convert it to **Unicode, UnicodeWithBOM, UTF-8**

```
The language samples below were generated using Google Translate.

Welcome to Unicode and International language support for source materials in our product.
[English]

مرحبا بكم في ويونيكود الدعم الدولي لمواد اللغة مصدر في منتجاتنا.
[Arabic]

歡迎國際語言支持Unicode和源材料在我們的產品。
[Chinese (Traditional)]

Καλώς ήρθατε στο Unicode και διεθνή γλωσσική υποστήριξη για πρώτες ύλες για το προϊόν μας.
[Greek]

ברוכים הבאים ל-Unicode ותמיכה בינלאומית השפה עבור חומרי המקור של המוצר שלנו.
[Hebrew]

Velkomin á Unicode og alþjóðleg tungumál styðja fyrir efni sem uppspretta í vörum okkar.
[Icelandic]

ようこそUnicodeと私たちの製品のソースの材料のための国際言語のサポート。
[Japanese]

Добро пожаловать в Unicode и международной языковой поддержки для исходных материалов в нашей продукции.
[Russian]
```

Comment: a byte array does not have any intrinsic coding, if you are talking about constrcuting strings then use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes,  I have string byte array

Comment: *I have an array of a byte in UTF-8 format*  - this is meaningless

Comment: @ScaryWombatI have updated my question pls check

Comment: Output looks exactly the same as input.

Answer (score 3):

To convert `byte[]` from UTF-8 to UTF-16:

```
byte[] utf8 = ...;

// With BOM
byte[] utf16 = new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16);

// Without BOM
byte[] utf16 = new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);
// or
byte[] utf16 = new String(utf8, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

bytes are bytes, the work is need to convert a String from a certain charset into bytes or concerting bytes into another charset.

consider the below code

```
    String input = "ウォンバット";
    byte[] b1 = input.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] b2 = input.getBytes("ISO8859-1");    // the Unicode block also called "Latin 1"
    byte[] b3 = input.getBytes(); // my system is UTF8
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(b1));
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(b2));
    System.out.println (Arrays.toString(b3));

    String out1 = new String (b1);  // my system is UTF8
    System.out.println(out1);   // good output
    out1 = new String (b2);
    System.out.println(out1);   // mungled    
    out1 = new String (b3);
    System.out.println(out1);   // good    

    out1 = new String (b1, "SJIS");
    System.out.println(out1);       // mungled
    out1 = new String (b1, "UTF8");
    System.out.println(out1);       // good
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is helpful for me.